# DDMathParser: nil value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math, ddmathparser

Sorry for my english, I try to explain better my problem:
I need to parse a math expression and then save the results inside a variable, this is my code:

```
for (i = -100; i < 100; i = i + step) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *variableSubstitutions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:i] forKey:@"x"];
    NSNumber *y = [[DDMathEvaluator sharedMathEvaluator] evaluateString:[self convertString:eq.equazione] withSubstitutions:variableSubstitutions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"y is: %@",y);
}
```

The NSLog have always a value, if I try to parse an expression like tan(x) the log never print a nil value, I need to display also the nil value if exist.
I try to check y value, error value but I don't find a way for handle nil value of expression.

Comment: sorry, I edit my question, I hope it is better then the first time.

Comment: For the input " tan(x)", what is the value of y and the error, NSLog error.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you want, if not please update your question.

```
NSNumber *y = [[DDMathEvaluator sharedMathEvaluator] evaluateString:[self convertString:eq.equazione] withSubstitutions:variableSubstitutions error:&error];
if(y)
    NSLog(@"y is: %@", y);
else
    NSLog(@"y is: nil");
```